# Open Chrome with a Script on any Windows OS from xp on up

Tags: vbscript, cmd

For a Windows PC I wanted a script that will open Google Chrome whether it be in %PROGRAMFILES%, %PROGRAMFILES% (x86), %LOCALAPPDATA% (XP), or %APPDATA% and if its not installed to report that Google Chrome is not installed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a vbscript.

The following command will determine where Chrome is installed and set the `CHROMEPATH` environment variable to this value.

**From the command line:**

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH="%c %d %e"
```

**From a batch file:**

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH="%%c %%d %%e"
```

After running this command (on my machine):

```
echo %CHROMEPATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

If `%CHROMEPATH%` is empty then Crome is not installed.

If it is not empty then you have the install location and you can run Chrome.

You can use `if` to test this.

runchrome.cmd

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH="%%c %%d %%e"

if exist %CHROMEPATH% (
  start "chrome" %CHROMEPATH%
  )
else (
  echo Chrome is not installed
)
```

I can't quite get the batch file to work as expected ... but you get the idea ...

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I may be able to figure this out now that I know how to get the correct path for chrome. After I ran it in cmd my chromepath is c:\programfiles\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe,0. I havent tested it on another OS yet but it looks good so far.

Comment: There is a space missing between "program" and files". I'm also having trouble with the spaces in the path. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

Code

```
@echo off
start chrome "site1.com" "site2.com"
quit
```

Then to report it ain't there try something like

```
IF NOT EXIST chrome.exe goto Unavailable

:Unavailable
echo Sorry, chrome.exe is not installed on this computer...
echo pause>nul
quit
```

Your Final code SHOULD look something like...

```
@echo off
IF NOT EXIST chrome.exe goto Unavailable
start chrome "site1.com" "site2.com"
quit

:Unavailable
echo Sorry, chrome.exe is not available on this computer...
pause>nul
quit
```

Better!!! 
Edit:

```
Dim URL 
Dim Execute

URL = "Your URL in which to navigate"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", URL, "", "", 1
```

Hope It Works!
If not just try to tell me the error it says,

Pringles

**Edited It a wee bit** Try the code, Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you for your help Pringles. If I remove the @ then the error I get in .vbs is Expected 'Then' Code 800A03F9. .CMD does not open chrome and echos message that its not installed but it is installed.

Comment: @Bobby Brown Try this... Open a new notepad window, then paste the code... This part is important, save it with the file extension .bat. Ex- file.bat, Clock.bat etc... Sorry about the .bat file extension needed, would you like me to make this into a .vbs? -Pringles

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I made the batch file a .bat but Chrome is not starting with it.  My chrome is located here: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" If I run in cmd "start chrome" then My Chrome browser does start so it’s beyond me why it’s not working.  I have also tried on several other PC with the same results. Also I do not get any errors. CMD echos Sorry, chrome.exe is not available on this computer.... Like it should if no chrome is installed.

Comment: All right, sorry, was on vacation, though I will certainly try to fix this:)

Comment: Is chrome your default browser?

Comment: Sorry, life got in the way. I wasn't having any luck with making .bat, .cmd, or .vbs. Probably because I was doing something wrong. I did get it to work making a .exe with Visual Basic 2010 applications. I will copy the code and paste it when I get home. Thank you for all your help Pringles

Comment: You are very welcome, if you need any more help then feel free to ask me and i will help you out:) If my code doesn't work maybe a compilation error, sorry, I will work on optimization, once again sir it was my pleasure!

Comment: This is for visual basic 2010 and works with chrome, firefox and safari.    Private Sub KryptonButton8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles KryptonButton8.Click
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Process.Start("chrome.exe", "www.google.com")
        End
errorHandler:
        MsgBox("Chrome is not installed.")
    End Sub

Comment: Great! Im glad you found a solution:)